# Не отвечает com порт с arduino ide для платы nodemcu

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, nodemcu

Написал простой код для потенциометра, но com порт на "0" не отвечает, да и на любые другие числа тоже. Помогите решить проблему.

```
#define UD  2                          // выходы к которым подключен модуль
#define INC 3
#define CS  4

void up(){                            // поднимает ползунок в верх на 1 ступень
  digitalWrite(UD, HIGH);             // на U/D подаем единицу
  digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);            // и на INC тоже
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);              // включаем микросхему
  delayMicroseconds(1);               // ждем
  digitalWrite(INC, LOW);             // дергаем вход INC
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
///digitalWrite(INC, LOW);                  // в этом случаи положение ползунка записано не будет
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);             // выключаем микросхему и записываем положение в EEPROM 
}

void down(){                          // опускаем ползунок в верх на 1 ступень
  digitalWrite(UD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(INC, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1);

  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(INC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(UD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);                         // выключаем микросхему
}

void loop() {

if (Serial.available()) {                       // проверяем пришло ли что в Serial
  if (Serial.read() == '0'){                   // если пришел 0                                    // опускаем ползунок
    Serial.print("-1");
    up();
    }
  else {                                       // иначе поднимаем
    Serial.print("+1");
    down();
    }
   
  }
 

}
```

Comment: А вы в самой Arduino IDE выставили скорость передачи 9600? Там по умолчанию стоит 115200

Comment: Да, выставил 9600 бодов

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте вот так и все будет работать:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0)
```

Единственное при таком исполнении Вашего кода, после выполнения `up` он выполнит  и `down`.